# Reseting rotation of UIView to 0

Tags: ios, uiview, frame, cgaffinetransform

How can I reset rotation of my View back to zero while keep other transformations on that view unchanged.

I cant use:

`[myView setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity]`

as it will rest all the other transforms too.

Or I just want the frame of the view if its rotation was 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
myView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(myView.transform, -currentRotationAngle);
```

this will take the current transform, and rotate it to 0 degrees

Edit: i think you will need to rotate by the inverse of your current rotation value, not just set it to 0

Comment: `CGAffineTransformRotate` doesn't help here, as it applies rotation of that angle to the existing rotation.

Comment: would it not return the rotation to zero, if you pass in e.g. -M_PI_2 if the current rotation was M_PI_2?

Comment: sure, but you have to know the current rotation in order to reset it like that.

Answer (score 0):

To reset the rotation while keeping the transition you could try this code:

```
  CGAffineTransform inverse = CGAffineTransformInvert(myView.affineTransform);
  inverse.tx = 0;
  inverse.ty = 0;
  myView.transform = inverse;
```